# doxygen not listing functions in nested namespaces

Tags: doxygen

I'm documenting my code and can't make doxygen to pick up 
functions inside nested namespaces. 
Googling around i didn't see anyone facing this problem, sorry if a duplicate.

```
namespace n1 {
 /*! @addtogroup n1
 *@{
  */

 /**
  * n2 is...
  */
 namespace n2 {

    /**
     *  n3 is...
     */
    namespace n3 {

        /**
         * function does...
         */
         static inline
         int  
         find() { }
    }
}
 /*@}*/
}
```

In the resulting documentation (html) I see all namespaces (`n1`, `n2`, `n3`) but don't see any functions (e.g. `find()` ). The page corresponding to n3 namespace contains none.

I also tried `EXTRACT_ALL` build flag, does not seem to help.

p/s/ doxygen is generated using Doxygen GUI for OS-X.

Comment: According to the Doxyfile and the manual: If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES doxygen will assume all entities in
documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available.
Private class members and static file members will be hidden unless
the EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC tags are set to YES

Comment: @albert as you see in the example above, these are not private. No idea why it does not document those

Comment: I just copied part of the manual here and maybe the word "and" between EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC is a bit confusing here, the word respectively might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set EXTRACT_STATIC = YES in your Doxyfile.

The comment on EXTRACT_ALL states, "Private class members and static file members will be hidden unless the EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC tags are set to YES"

I've tested with your example and setting EXTRACT_STATIC = YES and the find function is visible in the resulting documentation.